# CORS issues when trying to download content from S3 with Chrome, but works on Safari

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors

I have a React/Javascript application that tries to download a file from an S3 bucket. The code is working well on `Firefox`, `Safari` and `Chrome(Incognito mode)` , but it fails on **Chrome (regular mode)** and **Microsoft Edge**.

This is the code:

```js
const myUrl = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/..."
const response = await fetch(myUrl);
const blob = await response.blob();
```

[image: Image showing CORS error on Chrome]

This is my bucket policy on S3 bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*",
            "https://my-platform.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```